# print, put, say and escape characters

Tags: string, raku

According to the docs, the only difference between [`print`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/print) and [`say`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle#method_say) seems to be the fact that the latter adds "\n" (and stringifies using [`.gist`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/gist)). However,

```
perl6 -e 'print "del\b\b"'
```

prints "d", effectively applying escape characters, while

```
perl6 -e 'put "del\b\b"'
```

will output "del" (the same as `say`). Is it possible that there's a third way of stringifying strings, besides `.gist` and simple `.Str`?

As a matter of fact, any character behind the `\b` will make them behave in the same way. So any idea of why this happens?

Comment: Okay, I'm not seeing any difference in output between `~$ raku -e 'put "del";'` and `~$ perl6 -e 'print "del";'`. I would have expected the `print` statement to leave the shell prompt on the same line as the `del` output. I'm on iTerm2 (MacOS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FWIW, I see "del" in both cases, regardless of using `print` or `put`, so maybe there is some terminal setting that is affecting the behaviour?

The `\b\b` only become obvious when you actually put characters after them:

```
say "del\b\bo the right thing"  # do the right thing
```

`\b` only moves the cursor back one position.  It does not erase anything by itself.  If you want the characters erase, you'd have to have them followed by spaces, and then backspace again if you want any text after that again:

```
print "del\b\b  \b\b"           # d
```

Comment: There might. I'm using Gnome Terminal 3.6.2

Answer (score 7):

To see what's being output, without possible confusion of what the terminal might be doing, you can pipe through xxd (or od)

```
$ perl6 -e 'say "del\b\b"' | xxd
00000000: 6465 6c08 080a                           del...
$ perl6 -e 'print "del\b\b"' | xxd
00000000: 6465 6c08 08                             del..
$ perl6 -e 'put "del\b\b"' | xxd
00000000: 6465 6c08 080a                           del...
```